# Format in 2 background image

Tags: css, background-image

I wanted to make my `background-image` not adjustable when resizing the window and the only way I can think of is using `repeat-x` in `bg2.png` .My only problem is how to put the `background-size: 100%;` in `bg1.png`. Because if I will separate it in `bg1`, the `repeat-x` won't work.

```
body{
  background: url(../img/bg1.png) top no-repeat, url(../img/bg2.png) repeat-x;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you please show us screenshot of what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 body{
        background-image:url(background.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```